# Facebook Place Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I can't seem to find how to get facebook place's page like count via fql, anyone knows how this can be achieved? 
I know this can be done with graph-api but I need it in fql since I already have a multi-fql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page):

There is a parameter called `fan_count` that contains the number of people who like the page.